# Autofac - How can I tell if service was registered with interceptor?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I would like to throw an exception if service was registered with interceptor.
Is there a way to query the container about the registered interceptors?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to know this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Steven I have requirement to force interface interception on specific type

Comment: Just write a unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no built in query syntax to determine which services were registered with interceptors.